# Перенести значения в одинаковые ключи массива php

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Прошу помощи, уже не знаю в какую сторону смотреть.
Есть json строка.

```
$inp='{"code":{"A081":"249","A024":"212","A755":0,"A031":"230","A058":"195","A192":0,"D376":0,"D098":0,"d443":0,"d510":0,"D396":0,"D413":0,"D411":0,"D431":0,"D461":0,"D432":0,"d483":"215","d484":0,"D439":0,"A838":"216","D488":0,"a258":0,"D507":0,"A258":"225","d098":"233","d431":"240","d432":"239","d461":"245","d507":"203"}}';
```

В строке есть одинаковые ключи, такие как D507 и d507, по сути одно и тоже. Только есть одно но.
У первого ключа (D507) правильное название, но неправильное значение, которое равно нулю.
У второго ключа (d507) неправильное название, но правильное значение.

Как сделать так, соединив правильное название с правильным значением, т. е. чтобы на выходе получить:

```
$inp = {"code":{...,"D507":"203",...}}
```

При этом старого ключа (d507) в строке быть не должно. Возможно ли такое?

Начал вот так:

```
$dat = json_decode($inp, true);
$key = array();
$value = array();
foreach($dat['code'] as $k => $v){
$key[] = $k;
}
```

Также в строке присутствуют одиночные ключи со значением ноль, например d443 => 0.
Этот ключ считается правильным, т. к. у него нет дубля.

Попробовал сделать по совету Рустам Гимранов, но почему то не "схлопнулись" повторяющиеся ключи:

```
asort($data['drugstores']);
$key = array();
$val = array();
foreach($data['drugstores'] as $k => $v) {
    $key[] = $k;
    $val[] = $v;
}

$merge = array_combine($key, $val);

array_change_key_case($merge);
```

Comment: Значения всегда должны быть отличны от нуля или ситуация к примеру D376 = 0 тоже может быть?

Comment: Да - D376 = 0, такое тоже может, он считается правильным. Т. к. у него нет одинакового ключа.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно пройтись по всем ключам, написать регулярку с помощью которой вы ищете все вхождения ключа в массиве не смотря на регистр. Если вхождений больше 1 - берёте правильное значение, присваиваете его к верному ключу и вырезаете участок массива (array_slice).

Comment: Если порядок сортировки конечного массива не важен, то сначала `asort`, затем `array_change_key_case`, который "схлопнет" повторяющиеся ключи.

Comment: А не проще просто исключить ключи с нижнем регистром?) И да, может ли быть такое, что с верхним регистром не верно а с нижним верно? Если да, то тут уже нужно будет другой подход и без перебора и сверки никак.

Comment: Почему вы, не отвечаете на вопросы, мало того, что вопрос непонятный, так еще и молчите, заводя всех недоумие какое-то. Раз ключи могут быть в разных моментах верными, либо в верхнем, либо в нижнем и почему до-сих пор этого нет в вопросе? Или вы считаете, что каждый зашедший в вопрос, должен перечитывать все комменты?

Comment: Я прошу прощения, сейчас добавлю в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я может чего то недопонял, но почему нельзя решить задачу так -

```
foreach($data['code'] as $k => $v) {
     if((strtoupper($k)==$k)&&isset($data['code'][strtolower($k)])) { // если у нас ключ в верхнем регистре и есть такой же ключ в нижнем регистре
          $data['code'][strtolower($k)] = $v; // меняем значение
          unset($data['code'][$k]);  // удаляем
     }
}
```

Comment: Максим Степанов, спасибо вам огромное.

Answer (score 1):

Решение "в лоб". Рассмотрим все 4 варианта: а) есть оба ключа, верхний регистр первый; б) только верхний; в) только нижний; г) есть оба ключа, верхний регистр второй.

Для каждого ключа в цикле ищем пару в верхнем и в нижнем. В условии проверяем, действительно ли для этого ключа удалось И изменить регистр И найти с таким ключом альтернативное значение. Если да, то принимаем решение о том, какой ключ и какое значение исходных данных писать в итоговый массив.

```
$in = [
    'A1' => 0,
    'a1' => 1,

    'B2' => 2,

    'c3' => 3,

    'd4' => 4,
    'D4' => 0,
];
$out = [];
foreach ($in as $k => $v) {
    $kLow = strtolower($k);
    $kUp = strtoupper($k);
    // A -> a
    if ($kLow !== $k && array_key_exists($kLow, $in)) {
        $out[$k] = $in[$kLow];
    // a -> A
    } elseif ($kUp !== $k && array_key_exists($kUp, $in)) {
        $out[$kUp] = $v;
    // A, a
    } else {
        $out[$k] = $v;
    }
}

// array(4) {
//  ["A1"]=> int(1)
//  ["B2"]=> int(2)
//  ["c3"]=> int(3)
//  ["D4"]=> int(4)
// }
var_dump($out);
```

Comment: Все просто замечательно по вашему коду. Вот только если в массиве встречается не дублированный ключ со значением равным нулю (d483 = 0), ключ он переводит в верхний регистр D483, что не совсем верно.